# How to clear/reset variable in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am struggling to clear variable when new PowerApps form open. My requirement is to pass the argument from another screen to the Main screen. Variable gets receive successfully to the Main screen. However, when I submit the form and re-open the NEW form, that variable still holds the old value. How do I get rid of the resetting variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:
ResetForm(Form1);NewForm(Form1)
And then if you want Set(varName;Blank())

Comment: where to set this? Form OnSuccess? or During Navigating to Main Form?

Comment: I would do this before the Navigate() function

Comment: @marianr99- that work like a charm. Though I have used ResetForm earlier but didn't work. But ResetForm() followed with NewForm() worked. But how? I am still wondering. ResetForm() didn't reset varName variable and NewForm() did. How?

Comment: I don't know bro.. Microsoft always surprise me. I've tryed ResetForm alone and didn't expect it to fail.. Sometimes in powerapps we have to tryhard things with no sense 

Comment: Should be Set(varName, Blank()); Won't let me edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Set(*<VariableName>*, Blank());` cleared the value of the variable in my case. Use this command before trying to access or check the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

1. Navigate to the Main Screen with the variable reset: Before navigating to the Main Screen, ensure the variable is reset to its default value or to an empty string.

   ```
   Navigate(MainScreen, ScreenTransition.Fade, { YourVariable: "" })
   ```

   Replace MainScreen with the name of the screen where your form is located, and YourVariable with the name of your variable.
2. Reset the variable on Main Screen visibility: In the Main Screen's OnVisible property, reset the variable to its default value or to an empty string.

   ```
   UpdateContext({ YourVariable: "" })
   ```

Replace `YourVariable` with the name of your variable.

With these steps in place, whenever you navigate to the Main Screen with the form, the variable will be reset to its default value, ensuring that it doesn't retain the old value from previous submissions.